# add transition to css opacity change after exiting hover

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I'm having trouble adding a transition to the opacity change (back to 1 from 0.2 when exiting hover) for a hover state, an example is in this pen:
https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/MWqVREp

if I add `transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;` to the ul:has section of the css it gives me the transition effect I want when hovered, however it doesn't apply the transition when exiting the hover state. it instantly snaps back to opacity 1. where as I would like the same transition that applies to 1>0.2 to apply when 0.2>1

I have also tried this with making `ul:after` and `li:after` with the transition and it doesn't work there either

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:** https://codepen.io/astrowstorer/pen/rNZKVwv
in this example I have stylised to make the effect easier to see, and as per the solutions given in the thread found that the solution is adding the `transition` styling to both elements within the `li` as their exact/root element and not the state of the element, in this case both `<a>` and `<span>`

Comment: your codepan link is not working. It will be best if you will add code (html/css) in case of link not working so please update so we can try to help.

Comment: thanks, not sure why it broke, the url is correct and ive updated the link formatting. works for me now but the url is correct either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the transition to work on enter and exit you have to add the transition to the exact element instead of the state of the element.

Try adding the transition `transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;` to the 'a' tag

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, perhaps because of the interaction with the `<span>` and `<a>` tags with the has/not selector? Thats why I tried adding it to both the `<ul>` and `<li>` styles and their :after states as well... still doesn't apply a transition to 0.2>1

Comment: Sorry, after some tinkering following your answer this lead me to the solution perfectly. Amended the OP.

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help, would appreciate if you could upvote and accept it as the answer